# How can I rename a category in Visual Studio's DGML editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, dgml

I created a new UML component diagram to start laying out dependencies in a component I just "inherited". I wanted to mark the test projects in green, for example, and now the legend looks like:

[image: Visual Studio Diagram Legend]

Is there a way I can rename these categories to be something like "tests" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the guidance in MSDN here:

- [Assign categories to nodes and links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee842619.aspx#AssignCategories)
- [Change the style of nodes and links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee842619.aspx#Highlight)

Comment: Hi Esther, could you please help me with my question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497753/dgml-how-to-enable-the-go-to-definition-for-custom-diagrams

Comment: So, there is no visual way of doing so? Is it all done via code? Is it possible to hook somehow on the DGML viewer to make it possible? It seems such a waste of resources ;)