# DGML: how to enable the 'Go To Definition' for custom diagrams?

Tags: visual-studio, graph, visual-studio-extensions, graph-visualization, dgml

I am generating a custom workflow diagram via DGML API where each node corresponds to a C# class. I would like to be able to use the built-in 'Go To Definition' feature but the documentation is lacking.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the class´s filename and the position of the symbol definition, you can use the `VsShellUtilities` class to open the document and scroll the code artifact into the view (by setting the caret position). In one of my extensions I do something like this...

If have a `SourceInfo` type which I use to store the filename and text-range...

```
void GotoDefinition(
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider, 
    SourceInfo source)
{
    IVsUIHierarchy hierarchy;
    uint itemId;
    IVsWindowFrame windowFrame;
    IVsTextView view;

    VsShellUtilities.OpenDocument(
        serviceProvider,
        source.Filename,
        Guid.Empty,
        out hierarchy,
        out itemId,
        out windowFrame,
        out view);

    if (view != null)
    {
        int line, column;
        int pos = source.TextRange.Start;
        if (view.GetLineAndColumn(pos, out line, out column) == VSConstants.S_OK)
        {
            view.SetCaretPos(line, column);
            view.CenterLines(line, 1);
        }
    }
}

class SourceInfo
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public TextRange TextRange { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That is interesting, thank you, but I was wondering if it's just a matter of setting the right node category and label to make it work without any extra code.

Comment: How do generate the `DGML` graph? How is the graph connected to your code?

Comment: I am generating it manually. It's not but I was wondering if I could just follow the Code Maps conventions and get same functionality auto-magically. Unfortunately don't have more time to investigate, was wondering if someone already done that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify goto definition, but you can use "goto reference" instead.  If you manually edit the DGML file in a text editor you can add a "Reference" property to a node, like this:

```
<Node Id="Boomerang" Reference="Boomerang.dgml"/>
```

Then when you right click this node in VS you will see a new menu appear named "Go To Reference" with a submenu containing "Reference", if you click this it will open the referenced DGML file.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee842619.aspx#AddReferences for more detail.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is possible to modify the goto definition. It's just not documented well. Thank you for workaround though.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio have it's own property "SourceLocation"

You should declare it in properties

```
<Properties>
...
<Property Id="SourceLocation" Label="Start Line Number" DataType="Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphModel.CodeSchema.SourceLocation" />
...
</Properties>
```

then use it inside Node element f.e.

```
<Node Id="class1" Label="FirstClass" SourceLocation="(Assembly=file:///D:/Prj/TestApp/AppConsole/Program.cs StartLineNumber=8 StartCharacterOffset=1 EndLineNumber=8 EndCharacterOffset=1)"/>
```